# Solving integral $\int(2\lambda+f^2/2)\, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am referring to [this script, equations (39) and (40)][1]

The equation is
$$
w_{1x}=2\lambda+\frac{1}{2}w_1^2\tag{39}
$$
and it is said that this can be integrated to yield,
$$
w_{1}=-2k\tanh[kx+f(t)]\tag{40},
$$
where $\lambda=-k^2$ and $f$ is an arbitrary function.

My problem is to see that
$$
\int\left(2\lambda+\frac{1}{2}w_1^2\right)\, dx=-2k\tanh[kx+f(t)].
$$

How does one get that?

Comment: To solve this differential equation, one does not simply integrate both sides w.r.t. $x$ since both sides depend on the function $w_1:= w_1(x,t)$ you are trying to find. Instead, one can write
$$\frac{1}{2\lambda+\frac{1}{2}(w_1)^2}\frac{\partial w_1}{\partial x}=1,$$
and then integrate both sides w.r.t. $x$ (see [Separable equations](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/separable.aspx)).

Comment: Ah, ok. Separation of variables. And how to solve the integral on the left hand side? Integration by substitution?

Comment: The integral on the left is essentially a scalar multiple of the integral
$$\int \frac{1}{x^2-a^2}~dx$$
for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$. To solve that integral, you can either find it on a table, or you can apply the substitution $x=a\tanh(u)$ and use the identity $1-\tanh^2(u)=\operatorname{sech}^2(u)$.